# two different type of datas

Tags: angular, typescript, reducers

I have a problem, I have a code that works on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebay-filter-count-demo).

Component

```
let carTypeReducer = (acc, cur) => ({...acc, [cur.tipo]:(acc[cur.tipo] || 0 ) + 1})

from(this.carsService.getCars()).pipe(
  tap(data=> console.log(data))
  //scan(carTypeReducer,{})
).subscribe();
```

service:

```
getCars():Array<Car>{
  let cars:Car[] = [{modello:'X5', tipo:'jeep'},
                    {modello:'Q7', tipo:'jeep'},
                    {modello:'X1', tipo:'jeep'},
                    {modello:'500,', tipo:'citycar'},
                    {modello:'yaris', tipo:'citycar'},
                    {modello:'punto', tipo:'citycar'},
                    {modello:'C3', tipo:'citycar'}];
  return cars;
}
```

the log in the component return me this:

[image]

I don't know what type of data is this, I presume it is an array of object.
The problem is:the same code of the component don't works on vsc, I think because the data type is not the same.This is the log of vsc code

[image]

This is clearly an array of objects. But also the stackblitz code should return me an array of objects. What is the difference between the two? How can I make the same code work also on visual studio code with that type of data?I would like to specify that in vsc the data I receive from a database, they are not generated as in the stackblitz code. Thanks! P.S. I've tied to adjust layout, sorry.

UPDATE: I sew the shape of the data.
this code return me:

```
this.subscriptionTypeReducer = from(this.carsService.getCars())
      .subscribe(res => this.outputJSON = res);
```

shape of vsc data from sql backend:

```
[
  {
    "id": 20,
    "model": "Q7",
    "brand": "audi",
    "type": "jeep",
    "price": 70000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/audi_mod1_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/audi_mod1_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/audi_mod1_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 27,
    "username": "paperinik"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "model": "A1",
    "brand": "audi",
    "type": "berlina",
    "price": 22000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/audi_mod2_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/audi_mod2_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/audi_mod2_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 31,
    "username": "paperino"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "model": "X5",
    "brand": "bmw",
    "type": "jeep",
    "price": 67000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/bmw_x5_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/bmw_x5_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/bmw_x5_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 29,
    "username": "gastone"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "model": "SERIE 1",
    "brand": "bmw",
    "type": "berlina",
    "price": 27000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/bmw_serie1_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/bmw_serie1_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/bmw_serie1_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 27,
    "username": "paperinik"
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "model": "X1",
    "brand": "bmw",
    "type": "suv",
    "price": 31800,
    "image1": "CarsImages/bmw_x1_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/bmw_x1_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/bmw_x1_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 31,
    "username": "paperino"
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "model": "C1",
    "brand": "citroen",
    "type": "CityCar",
    "price": 10000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/citroen_c1_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/citroen_c1_img3.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/citroen_c1_img2.jpg",
    "userId": 30,
    "username": "paperoga"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "model": "C5",
    "brand": "citroen",
    "type": "suv",
    "price": 25000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/citroen_c5_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/citroen_c5_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/citroen_c5_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 28,
    "username": "ziopaperone"
  },
  {
    "id": 35,
    "model": "portofino",
    "brand": "ferrari",
    "type": "sportiva",
    "price": 195000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/ferrari_portofino_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/ferrari_portofino_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/ferrari_portofino_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 28,
    "username": "ziopaperone"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "model": "500",
    "brand": "fiat",
    "type": "CityCar",
    "price": 10900,
    "image1": "CarsImages/fiat_500_img1.jpeg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/fiat_500_img2.jpeg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/fiat_500_img3.jpeg",
    "userId": 29,
    "username": "gastone"
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "model": "500 X Lounge",
    "brand": "fiat",
    "type": "suv",
    "price": 21600,
    "image1": "CarsImages/fiat_500XLounge_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/fiat_500XLounge_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/fiat_500XLounge_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 29,
    "username": "gastone"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "model": "ghibli",
    "brand": "maserati",
    "type": "sportiva",
    "price": 71000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/maserati_ghibli_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/maserati_ghibli_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/maserati_ghibli_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 27,
    "username": "paperinik"
  },
  {
    "id": 33,
    "model": "levante",
    "brand": "maserati",
    "type": "suv",
    "price": 75900,
    "image1": "CarsImages/maserati_levante_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/maserati_levante_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/maserati_levante_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 30,
    "username": "paperoga"
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "model": "MC20",
    "brand": "maserati",
    "type": "sportiva",
    "price": 200000,
    "image1": "CarsImages/maserati_mc20_img1.jpg",
    "image2": "CarsImages/maserati_mc20_img2.jpg",
    "image3": "CarsImages/maserati_mc20_img3.jpg",
    "userId": 30,
    "username": "paperoga"
  }
]
```

shape of mock's data:

```
{
  "modello": "C3",
  "tipo": "citycar"
}
```

we can see that from the first we have an array of objects and the second just an object. So how can I fix the reducer to use with first case?
reducer:

```
let carTypeReducer = (acc, cur) => ({...acc, [cur.type]:(acc[cur.type] || 0) +1 })

    this.subscriptionTypeReducer = from(this.carsService.getCars())
      .pipe(
        scan(carTypeReducer, {})
      ).subscribe();
```

Comment: `from(this.carsService.getCars())` would give you an observable of items from the array, whereas `of(this.carsService.getCars())` would give you an observable of the whole array. It seems like the latter might be closer to what you're getting for real, but it's not clear from this what your actual problem is.

Comment: for example I can't access to item's property of the array in vsc, while in stackblitz I can do it, so the reducer works.

Comment: Then investigate the difference, but without a [mre] we can't tell you why.

Comment: Where are you getting these objects with `id`, `model`, and `brand` properties from in your VSCode image (images of text are discouraged, see [ask])?  They are not present in your example code or in stackblitz so I'm not sure how to advise.   A [mcve] would be helpful here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe scuse me but i can t do a sql database on stackblitz,can t we infer the type from the log? In addition I can say that I retrieve the data from a simple sql backend and get they with http.get call

Comment: @jcalz I get it with an http get call to a backend that query sql database

Comment: So... the difference is that your mock objects are the wrong shape.  If suggest you change your code to conform to the `{id: number, model: string, brand: string, ...}` format that is returned from the back end.  Or you have to write your own conversion function.  Without a [mcve] I'm not prepared to walk you through that.

Comment: I have updated the informations post, we have more details.

Comment: I solved, I used mergeAll() before scan